# Obtain a switch/case behaviour in Perl 5

Tags: perl, switch-statement

Is there a neat way of making a case or switch statement in Perl 5?. It seems to me they should include a switch on version 6.

I need this control structure in a script, and I've heard you can import a "switch module". But how can I achieve it without imports to minimize dependencies and acquire portability?

Comment: The Switch module is part of Core Perl, and has been since 5.8, so there is no dependency issue; however, it does have some bugs and limitations.  See the docs for more info, or better yet, upgrade to 5.10 and get a switch statement, smart match operator, say function, state variables, a host of regex improvements, defined-or (//), stacked file test operators (-r -x $file instead of -r $file && -x _), and a host of other improvements.

Comment: See [this perlfaq7 question](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7#How-do-I-create-a-switch-or-case-statement?). (Don't use given/when or the Switch module.)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you are using Perl 5.10 you have [`given`/`when`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements) which is a switch statement (note, it can do more than compare with regexes, read the linked docs to see its full potential):

```
#or any of the dozen other ways to tell 5.10 to use its new features
use feature qw/switch/; 

given($string) {
    when (/^abc/) { $abc     = 1; }
    when (/^def/) { $def     = 1; }
    when (/^xyz/) { $xyz     = 1; }
    default       { $nothing = 1; }
}
```

If you are using Perl 5.8 or earlier you must make do with `if`/`elsif`/`else` statements:

```
if    ($string =~ /^abc/) { $abc     = 1; }
elsif ($string =~ /^def/) { $def     = 1; }
elsif ($string =~ /^zyz/) { $xyz     = 1; }
else                      { $nothing = 1; }
```

or nested [condition operators (`?:`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator):

```
$string =~ /^abc/ ? $abc     = 1  :
$string =~ /^def/ ? $def     = 1  :
$string =~ /^xyz/ ? $xyz     = 1  :
                    $nothing = 1;
```

There is a module in Core Perl ([Switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html)) that gives you fake switch statements via [source filters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfilter.html), but it is my understanding that it is [fragile](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html#BUGS):

```
use Switch;

switch ($string) {
    case /^abc/ {
    case /^abc/ { $abc     = 1 }
    case /^def/ { $def     = 1 }
    case /^xyz/ { $xyz     = 1 } 
    else        { $nothing = 1 }
}
```

or the alternate syntax

```
use Switch 'Perl6';

given ($string) {  
    when /^abc/ { $abc     = 1; }
    when /^def/ { $def     = 1; }
    when /^xyz/ { $xyz     = 1; }
    default     { $nothing = 1; }
}
```

Comment: The Perl 5.10 version sets $_ like it does in Perl 6. the Switch module's given/when doesn't.

Comment: 'when' is an implicit '~~' operator, so not only regexes are allowed.

Comment: given/when is an experimental feature that's been deemed a failure. It shouldn't used as it can be removed/changed without warning. /// The Switch module uses source filters and do their own parsing of the Perl code. This leads to very weird error messages that are basically impossible to make sense of. It should be avoided as well.

Comment: I concur that given/when is evil. It creates nasty bugs in a code that works just fine under another Perl build (using v5.10.1 in both environments). I came here looking for the official alternative, if it exists.

Answer (score 20):

The suggestion in Programming Perl is:

```
for ($string) {
    /abc/ and do {$abc    = 1; last;};
    /def/ and do {$def    = 1; last;};
    /xyz/ and do {$xyz    = 1; last;};
    $nothing = 1;
}
```

Comment: From the docs: "do BLOCK does not count as a loop, so the loop control statements `next`, `last`, or `redo` cannot be used to leave or restart the block." https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html So `last` seems at least unnecessary?

Comment: the `do` block isn't part of a loop, but the `last` refers to the `for` loop, not to the `do`.

Comment: This still has the dangers of `given`/`when`, without the warning. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71010648/3092394

Answer (score 11):

Just a short comment about the core [Switch](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Switch) module that's been mentioned a couple of times in answers. The module in question relies on source filters. Among other things, that may result in wrong lines reported for errors. It's so bad that none of the core developers really remembers or cares to remember why it was accepted into the perl core in the first place.

Furthermore, Switch.pm will be the first Perl module ever to be removed from the perl core. The next major release of perl, 5.12.0, will still have it, albeit with a deprecation warning. That deprecation warning will go away if you explicitly install Switch.pm from CPAN. (You get what you ask for.) In the next release down the road, 5.14, Switch.pm will be entirely removed from core.

Answer (score 9):

An equivalent solution that I like is a [dispatch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table).

```
my $switch = {
  'case1' => sub { print "case1"; },
  'case2' => sub { print "case2"; },
  'default' => sub { print "unrecognized"; }
};
$switch->{$case} ? $switch->{$case}->() : $switch->{'default'}->();
```

Comment: Shorter: `($switch->{$case} || $switch->{default})->()`

Comment: This is beautiful!

Comment: concatenating variables for `$case` makes this very efficient for complex logic

Answer (score 1):

```
print("OK : 1 - CANCEL : 2\n");
my $value = <STDIN>;
SWITCH: {
    ($value == 1) && last(SWITCH);
    ($value == 2) && do {print("Cancelled\n"); exit()};
    print("??\n");
}
```

Comment: Please consider add some description of your answer.